# Most efficient way to return a random specific sample size in sql / coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I need to return some values based on a sample size.  So if a user selects 5% they would get a query resulting in a random 5% of rows from the origonal query.  Is there a way I can achieve this with just sql?

Currently the process is to run the query then generate random numbers to remove rows until only 5% is left, then build a new query off the rows that are left.  I do not believe this is the most efficient way, any better ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What back end? Some support this out of the box, eg. [SQL Server Limiting Result Sets by Using TABLESAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Person 
TABLESAMPLE (5 PERCENT) ;
```

In any system you should try to filter on the server, not on the client. Eg. you could use MySQLs [`CRC32`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_crc32) to compute a row checksum and then use this checksum to qualify 5% rows. Or use [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) to similar effect. Whatever you do, just don't fetch the entire table and filter rows on the client.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use TABLESAMPLE()

Comment: please be more specific - _why_ can't you use it?  what dbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I have a datasource created from an oracle server

Comment: @Todd Im not sure if its the coldfusion causing the error or what, but the syntax is not allowed it especially does not like the ';'

Comment: Did you try querying the db directly thru your standard query editor for Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

@Remus Rusanu has the best approach in terms of using the database server. But if you're doing on the application server, here's a method relying on CF. It pulls back all IDs, which is smaller than getting the entire row for each record, samples those and then goes back to the database for the full records.

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT id FROM myTable
</cfquery>

<cfset sampleSize = ceiling(data.recordcount * .05)>
<cfset idsInterred = 0>
<cfset ids = {}>

<cfloop condition="idsInterred LT sampleSize">
    <cfset newId = data['id'][randRange(1, sampleSize)]>
    <cfif NOT structKeyExists(ids, newId)>
        <cfset idsInterred++>
        <cfset ids[newId] = true>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT *
FROM myTable
<!--- assuming ids are integers --->
WHERE id IN (#structKeyList(ids)#) 
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="data">
    <!--- do stuff here --->
</cfloop>
```

Comment: The cfqueryparam, with list=true, will result in each element of the list being check to see if it can be cast to an Integer, and sent as individual params, eg. IN (?,?,?). That can slow things down considerably. In addition, some RDBMs are very particular to the total number of arguments that can be passed in a single statement, so you need to be careful using a method like this. If you have too many rows/too large a sample size, you could exceed that list. I've bumped up against it many times on MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Mark: fair enough, the `<cfqueryparam/>` isn't needed here. Another option is iterating over the struct and retrieving one record at a time or window over sets of ids.